# Convert raw SQL to Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Could someone show how to convert the following SQL query to the Django QuerySet call? I'm a new to Django and I could use the raw query, but it's interesting for me to know how do this query could be written as a native Django call.

There are 2 models User & Profile 1:1 
I need to fetch the emails from the User and the phone from the Profile if the same phone number appears in 2 or more profiles.

`SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(u.email) as emails, p.phone as phone_number
FROM
    profile AS p JOIN auth_user AS u on u.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY
    phone
HAVING
    COUNT(phone) > 1`

Here what I tried to do:

```
from myapp.models import Profile
from django.db.models import Count

Profile.objects
       .exclude(phone='')
       .annotate(phone_count=Count('phone'))
       .values('phone')
```

..and the result is:

```
[
  {
    'phone': '***'
  },
  {
    'phone': '***'
  }
]
```

If to add `.filter(phone_count__gt=1)` to the query then an empty result will be returned (don't understand why).

The desired output is:

```
[
    {
      'phone': '***',
      'emails': 'user1@mail.com'
    },
    {        
      'phone': '***',
      'emails': 'user2@mail.com,user3@mail.com'
    }
  ]
```

**UPD**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: You should show how you've tried to convert it yourself.

Comment: @Sayse added more description.

Comment: It would help if you could show the relevant parts of the `Profile` model, although the results you've shown here only have the one phone number, hence why adding the filter returns no results

Comment: @Sayse added a part of the `Profile` model. the desired result should contain a phone number and a list of email addresses, but I don't know if Django can fetch a list of `emails: ['user1@mail.com', 'user2@mail.com']` so I'm trying to use the group_concat, but if it could be solved some easier that would be great.

Comment: You should try to create an [mcve], django's user model doesn't have a list of emails, and its not clear what value the count of a charfield would have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from myapp.models import Profile
from django.db.models import Count

qs = Profile.objects.exclude(
    phone=''
).exclude(
    phone__isnull=True
).values('phone').annotate(
    phone_count=Count('user_id')
).filter(
    phone_count__gt=1
).values_list('phone', flat=True)
# the above will get you a list of phone numbers that appear more than once
# now get the user_ids, too, and add in the emails
qs = Profile.objects.filter(phone__in=qs).values_list('user__email', 'phone')
# now convert to a dict
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
for email, phone in qs:
    data[phone].append(email)
# now convert to desired format
result = [{
    'phone': phone,
    'emails': ','.join(emails),
} for phone, emails in data.itervalues()]

# Of course, you could always just use raw and do a raw
# SQL query as described here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly
```